# Synology DiskStation: How to stop/interrupt a running reshape (RAID5 -> RAID6)

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

*The short of it:* I have a running reshape from RAID5 with 5 disks to RAID6 with 6 disks which needs to be stopped, so I can power off the system. I do not care if the reshape needs to start fresh once I reboot it, but I would prefer keeping my data intact.

*The longer:*

**System:** Synology DiskStation 1819+ with DSM 6.2.2-24922

**Running command:** `/sbin/mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --force -l 6 -n 6 --backup-file=/etc/raid/bkp_reshape/md2_20190724_170727` (started via GUI, the backup file location is on md0)

**Backups:** Available, if not of everything.

When I started the operation I was thinking of a couple of days running, but it is so slow that the projected time exceeds 40 days, which I cannot meet, as I am moving and the DS needs to be powered down on Monday at the latest.

Here's some console output:

```
# uname -a
Linux xxxx 4.4.59+ #24922 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 10 02:49:58 CST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_denverton_1819+

# mdadm --version
mdadm - v3.4 - 28th January 2016

# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md2 : active raid6 sdf3[5] sda3[0] sde3[4] sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sdb3[1]
      46856253440 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 18 [6/5] [UUUUU_]
      [>....................]  reshape =  3.7% (439918592/11714063360) finish=111378.6min speed=1686K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sdf2[5] sda2[0] sdb2[1] sdc2[2] sdd2[3] sde2[4]
      2097088 blocks [8/6] [UUUUUU__]

md0 : active raid1 sdf1[5] sda1[0] sdb1[1] sdc1[2] sdd1[3] sde1[4]
      2490176 blocks [8/6] [UUUUUU__]

unused devices: <none>

# mdadm --detail /dev/md2 
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Jun 10 12:16:53 2019
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 46856253440 (44685.61 GiB 47980.80 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 11714063360 (11171.40 GiB 11995.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Jul 26 09:39:20 2019
          State : clean, degraded, reshaping 
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric-6
     Chunk Size : 64K

 Reshape Status : 3% complete
     New Layout : left-symmetric

           Name : xxxx:2  (local to host xxxx)
           UUID : b6f288df:931fae61:03ecf298:60352fb4
         Events : 754587

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       4       8       67        4      active sync   /dev/sde3
       5       8       83        5      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdf3
```

Of course I've had a look around, and I found this:

`echo frozen > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`

to stop/pause the operation

`echo idle > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`   OR

`echo reshape > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action`

to resume

What I don't know about this is if this really works with reshape and not only with (re)sync.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, before I have to force a shutdown.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

OK this worked for me:

- `echo frozen > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action` stopped the mdadm process
- issuing `echo idle > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action` led to sync_action instantly switching to *reshape*, but the mdadm process didn't restart
- I then rebooted, and after the system came back up again the reshape process picked up where it had left off. Everything else looks good.

**EDIT 2**

Today, after running for 48 days (plus the couple of days before I moved), the process finished successfully.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311051/how-to-continue-an-mdadm-grow-after-a-reboot